# How can i achieve this mouse movement triggered animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, interactive

I found  [this animation](http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2015/05/flat-design-vs-material-design-what-makes-them-different.html#.VUznf_lViko)  activated by mouse movement and just wondering how to achieve this.

Is there anyone have done this or share some tutorial site?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Bind to mouse move and then calculate the center of the screen. Calculate the offset between the center of the screen and the mouse location. (I would use an easing function so it would max out at some point). Then simply set the image to whatever value comes out of the easing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect is called "parallax".

There's a few libraries that make easier to create it.

In a quick search I found this one: [Parallax.js](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax) (demo avaliable [here](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/))

It's easily implemented using:

```
<ul id="scene">
  <li class="layer" data-depth="0.00"><img src="layer1.png"></li>
  <li class="layer" data-depth="0.20"><img src="layer2.png"></li>
  <li class="layer" data-depth="0.40"><img src="layer3.png"></li>
  <li class="layer" data-depth="0.60"><img src="layer4.png"></li>
  <li class="layer" data-depth="0.80"><img src="layer5.png"></li>
  <li class="layer" data-depth="1.00"><img src="layer6.png"></li>
</ul>
```

And javascript:

```
var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
var parallax = new Parallax(scene);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code and demo. That really helps a lot.